# Ruby: parse yaml from ANSI to UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, yaml

**Problem:**

I have the yaml file `test.yml` that can be encoded in UTF-8 or ANSI:

```
:excel:
  "Test":
    "eins_Ä": :eins
    "zwei_ä": :zwei
```

When I load the file I need it to be encoded in UTF-8 therefore tried to convert all of the Strings:

```
require 'yaml'
file = YAML::load_file('C:/Users/S61256/Desktop/test.yml')

require 'iconv'
CONV = Iconv.new("UTF-8", "ASCII")

class Test

    def convert(hash)
        hash.each{ |key, value| 
            convert(value) if value.is_a? Hash
            CONV.iconv(value) if value.is_a? String
            CONV.iconv(key) if key.is_a? String
        }
    end

end

t = Test.new
converted = t.convert(file)

p file
p converted
```

But when I try to run this example script it prints:

`in 'iconv': eins_- (Iconv:IllegalSequence)`

**Questions:**

**1.** Why does the error show up and how can I solve it?

**2.** Is there another (more appropiate) way to get the file's content in UTF-8?

**Note:**
I need this code to be compatible to Ruby 1.8 as well as Ruby 2.2. For Ruby 2.2 I would replace all the Iconv stuff with String::encode, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deal with wrong encoded files is to read it in its original encoding, convert to UTF-8 and then pass to receiver (YAML in this case):

```
▶ YAML.load File.read('/tmp/q.yml', encoding: 'ISO-8859-1').force_encoding 'UTF-8'
#⇒ {:excel=>{"Test"=>{"eins_Ä"=>:eins, "zwei_ä"=>:zwei}}}
```

For Ruby 1.8 you should probably use `Iconv`, but the whole process (read as is, than encode, than yaml-load) remains the same.